# Fast rendering to buffer in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I have a Kivy application that uses matplotlib to render figures in the application GUI. It means that the application creates a matplotlib Figure and get the Figure's buffer to display it in an [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=image) widget.

For now, each time I want to update the figure, I recreate a Figure and draw everthing, calling `refresh_gui_image`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_matplotlib_buffer(image, *elements):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=200)
    ax = plt.Axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axis(ax)
    ax.imshow(image)
    for elem in elements:
        # Suppose such a function exists and return a matplotlib.collection.PatchCollection
        patchCollection = elem.get_collection()
        ax.add_collection(patchCollection)
    
    buffer = fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()
    plt.close(fig)
    return buffer

# imageWidget is a kivy Widget instance
def refresh_gui_image(imageWidget, image, *elements):
    size = image.shape()
    imageBuffer = draw_matplotlib_buffer(image, *elements)
    imageWidget.texture.blit_buffer(imageBuffer, size=size, colorfmt='rgba', bufferfmt='ubyte')
    imageWidget.canvas.ask_update()
```

In the code above, `*elements` represent multiple sets of objects. Typically, I have 2 to 4 sets which contains between 10 to 2000 objects. Each objects is represented with a patch, and each set is a PatchCollection on the Figure.

It works very well. With the current code, every patch is redrawn each time `refresh_gui_image` is called. When the sets becomes bigger (like 2000) objects, the update is too slow (few seconds). I want to make a faster rendering with matplotlib, **knowing that** some of the sets do not have to be redrawn, and that the image stays in the background, and do not have to be redrawn either.

I know blitting and animated artists can be used, this is what I tried, following [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html) of the matplotlib documentation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fig and ax are now global variable
# bg holds the background that stays identical 
fig = None
ax = None
bg = None

def init_matplotlib_data(image, *elements):
    global fig, ax, bg
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=200)
    ax = plt.Axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axis(ax)
    ax.imshow(image)
    fig.canvas.draw() # I don't want a window to open, just want to have a cached renderer
    bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)

    for elem in elements:
            # Suppose such a function exists and return a matplotlib.collection.PatchCollection
            patchCollection = elem.get_collection(animated=True)
            patchCollection.set_animated(True)
            ax.add_collection(patchCollection)

def draw_matplotlib_buffer(image, *artists_to_redraw):
    global fig, ax, bg
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)

    for artist in artists_to_redraw:
        ax.draw_artist(artist)
    
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    buffer = fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()
    return buffer
```

I call `init_matplotlib_data` once, and the `refresh_gui_image` as many time as I need, with artists I need to update. The point is that I correctly get my image background, but I cannot succeed to get the patches collections on the buffer returned by `fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()`. I unset the `animated` flag of the collection and this time they appear correctly. It seems to me, after some tests that `ax.draw_artist()` and `fig.canvas.blit()`  have no effect. Another behavior I do not understand is that event if I pass `animated=True` to `ax.imshow(image)`, the image is still drawn.

**Why does the `ax.draw_artist` and `fig.canvas.blit` functions does not update the buffer returned by `fig.canvas.print_to_buffer` as expected ?**

Comment: ["Not all backends support blitting. You can check if a given canvas does via the FigureCanvasBase.supports_blit property."](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html)

Comment: Actually, the Agg backend support blitting. The `supports_blit` property looks for the two functions `copy_from_bbox` and `restore_region` in the FigureCanvas, which FigureCanvasAgg has.

Comment: Even if blitting to the GUI does nothing, I should be able to use `restore_region` and `copy_from_bbox` to update the canvas. But I need to selectively redraw some artist, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Yes, I just tested `FigureCanvasBase.supports_blit`, and it returned `False` for a backend that supports blitting. Not sure why, though. I suggest breaking your problems down into smaller chunks. When I see a question with lots of code and four subquestions, I immediately feel discouraged to put any effort into it.

Comment: I edited the question to point out one particular problem, and reduce a bit the amount of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, blitting is a particular feature meant for GUI. Even thought the Agg backend support blitting, it does not mean that blitting can be used solely with it.

I came up with a solution where I store every artist I want to draw, and change their data whenever I need. I then use `fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()`, I am not sure what it does exactly, but I think the figure is fully redrawn. It is probably not as fast as what blitting can do, but it has the advantage to not reallocate and recreate every artists for each update. One can also remove artists from the canvas by calling the `remove()` method of an artist, and put it again with `ax.add_artist(..)`.

I think this solution answer my question, since it is the fastest solution to have dynamic plotting with matplotlib while dumping the canvas into a buffer.